# mongodb and aggregate multiple items

Tags: mongodb

i have this code

```
> db.attributes.aggregate([{ $match: {"name.en-UK": "Size"} },{ $unwind : "$values" },{ $project: { "code" : "$values.code", "name" : "$values.name", "_id": "$values._id"} },{ $match: {"name.en-UK": "S"}}])
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53b2c644d901f244965f74e3"),
            "code" : 0,
            "name" : {
                "en-UK" : "S"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53b2c644d901f244965f74e4"),
            "code" : 1,
            "name" : {
                "en-UK" : "S"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

how do i change it so that it returns only "code" == 0 with "name" == "en-UK" : "S"

i tried this:

```
> db.attributes.aggregate([{ '$match': {"name.en-UK": "Size"} },
... { '$unwind' : "$values" },
... { '$project': { "code" : "$values.code", "valueId": "$values._id"} },
... { '$match': {
... $and: [
... {"name.en-UK": "S"},
... {"code": 0}
... ]
... }
... }])
{ "result" : [ ], "ok" : 1 }
```

but is not working!

and advice much appreciated

Comment: Not the first post where you seem to be reviewing code that you do not understand and are asking for explanations. The answers are quite simple if you take the time and understand the basics of working with MongoDB. This is **Not** a help you with the contract you accepted service.

Comment: The edit is not helping. The path "name.en-UK" clearly does not match any data for "Size". Please do some reading first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems i need to add what to `select`, so `{ $project: { "code" : "$values.code", "name" : "$values.name", "_id": "$values._id"} }` must include the name

```
> db.attributes.aggregate([{ '$match': {"name.en-UK": "Size"} }, { '$unwind' : "$values" }, { $project: { "code" : "$values.code", "name" : "$values.name", "_id": "$values._id"} }, { '$match': { $and: [  {"name.en-UK": "S"},  {"code": 0} ] } }])
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53b2c644d901f244965f74e3"),
            "code" : 0,
            "name" : {
                "en-UK" : "S"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```